# What is the best practice for customizing a plugin's JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: theme-development, customization, jquery, javascript

Most well written plugins support a safe means for a developer to customize/theme the plugin by copying PHP files to the theme directory and modifying the copies rather than the original plugin file. But, unless I'm overlooking something, I'm not aware of any that support this with JavaScript/jQuery files.

What is the best practice or approach for customizing the plugin's JavaScrpt/jQuery files in an `upgrade safe` manner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a Plugin is coded properly, it will:

1. Use core-bundled jQuery, and any other core-bundled script, rather than bundling/using custom versions of such scripts
2. *enqueue* its scripts, via `wp_enqueue_script()`, hooked into an appropriate hook, via an explicit function

So, for such a Plugin:

1. You won't need to worry about customizing/overriding core-bundled scripts, since the Theme will be using the core-bundled versions as well
2. You can override custom scripts bundled with the Plugin by *dequeueing* the Plugin's scripts, and *enqueueing* your own custom versions

To override a Plugin's scripts, you have a few options:

1. Call [**`remove_action()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action) to remove the entire callback that contains the `wp_enqueue_script()` calls
2. Call [**`wp_dequeue_script()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_script) to *prevent* the script from being enqueued, followed by a [**`wp_enqueue_script()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) call to enqueue your own script.
3. Call [**`wp_deregister_script()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_deregister_script), followed by [**`wp_register_script()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script) (with the same script `$handle` to allow your own custom version to be registered, and enqueued in place of the Plugin's version

Comment: I like the answer; very informative and not too far from my thoughts. Nice to know I was on the right track. Any issue(s) with loading/queuing order with this approach?

Comment: *"Any issue(s) with loading/queuing order with this approach?"* - Possibly. You'll need to *dequeue* from the same action, at the same priority. If you `remove_action()`, you'll just need to make sure you call it after the `add_action()`.